# jquery flot chart does not update X axis values dynamically for time series

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, flot

I want my chart's x axis to be changed for given data. I put a sample code into [fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/deborad/q4qakg4g/5/) X axis is based on the time series. I dynamically set values. I use `tickFormatter: function(value){}` to format my time and show in page. The values set at first time is shown. (The browser gives alerts of the `tickFormatter` function. But when data is added later, that function seems to be not invoked) but values which are set dynamically are not shown.

I do not use jquery flot time plugin. If the chart values are not set dynamically, then chart shows x and y axis values with time series. Any one let me know how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution my self and I post it if some one faces the same problem.

What all have to do is add `plot.setupGrid();` before `plot.draw();` . Grids are reassigned.
These [fiddles](http://jsfiddle.net/jfazler/gQaUz/) helped me.